# flutter plugin don't work well after fork in GitHub

Tags: flutter, github, dart-pub

I'm using a Flutter plugin called cell_info version 0.2.9 to this date, but I found a problem in the plugin so forked it from Github and fixed it and used git URL in pubspec.yaml like this:

```
cell_info:
    git:
      url: http://github.com/flycomm-tech/FlutterCellInfo.git
```

But something strange happened, in pubspec.lock the version changed from 0.2.9 to 0.1.8
and the plugin works well in debug mode and also profile mode but not release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. the git that was connected to the plugin  in dart pub was not the actual plugin who uploaded to the pub. so I copied the library plugin who installed locally in C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org
and I fixed the bug there.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried also putting ref?

like arrangement like this

```
cell_info:
  git: 
    url: <your fork repo>
    ref: master (or which or what branch)
```

Comment: yes, I think the problem is from the plugin itself, not the git request. but thanks